# Hiding only checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I made a list of checkbox like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="Hide" class="Hide" />Hide</label>
 

            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
                    <label>                
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="f1" class="selector" />F1</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="f2" class="selector" />F2</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="f3" class="selector" />F3</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="f4" class="selector" />F4</label>
                                      
            </form> 
            <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
             <label>                
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="1" class="selector" />1</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="2" class="selector" />2</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="3" class="selector" />3</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="4" class="selector" />4</label>
                                      
            </form>
```

Since there are too many checkboxes, I'd like to hide unnecessary ones. I need mostly the ones with class="all". Can I hide the checkboxes with class="selector" keeping their labels visible. I made another checkbox for this purpose with class="Hide" at the top.

Comment: `$('.selector').hide()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need jquery and if you are using PHP as the scripting language, then this may be helpful:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['hide'])){?>
    <style type="text/css">
    .selector1{
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    </style><?php
}
if(isset($_POST['show'])){?>
    <style type="text/css">
    .selector1{
        display: inline-block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    </style><?php
}
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label>                
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="f1" class="selector1" />F1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="f2" class="selector1" />F2
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="f3" class="selector1" />F3
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="f4" class="selector1" />F4
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="hide" value="Hide"/>
    <input type="submit" name="show" value="Show"/>
</form>
```

**EDIT**
Working now!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hide"/> Hide
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <label>                
            <input type="checkbox" id="SelectAll" class="all" />All
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="f1" class="selector1" />F1
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="f2" class="selector1" />F2
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="f3" class="selector1" />F3
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="f4" class="selector1" />F4
        </label>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#hide").on( "click", function() {
        $(".selector1").toggle();
    });
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am not using php. I can hide them actually but can't bring them back :)

Comment: Check the EDIT please! I guess that is what you need.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. there is a "hide" checkbox to hide unnecessary checkboxes, i use it for this.  $( "#hide").on( "click", function() {
        $(".selector").toggle();
    });

Comment: That might be because you are doing something wrong. Copy the entire code exactly how is written. JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/zemc10b2/  LE: Check again the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/zemc10b2/1/

Comment: thanks a lot. I finally found out what i was doing wrong. there was some unnecessary code I left in js file. it was causing the problem. your code is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

> why use jQuery for this when css can do it easily (that was the whole reason it was designed to manipulate the UI view)

place this code at the top of your page.

this will hide your `.Hide` input box.. if you want to apply this on `.selector` just change `.Hide` to `.selector`

```
<style>
     .Hide{
      display:none;
      }
</style>
```

i put this in style tags as you probably don't know what a stylesheet is.. best practice is to put it in a stylesheet though.

i dont know what you mean by keeping the labels of the `.selector` if you dont want the input box you can just use a `<p>exmaple</p>` tag to put text in your web page

> JQuery way would be

```
$('.Hide').hide();
```

Comment: I need a button or another checkbox, so when needed, it can be made visible again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery in your html if you want to do it later in the page,

```
$(".hide , .all").hide();
```

Load Jquery from here:
    http://jquery.com/

otherwise make css display:none